# Is my actor based store really thread safe?

Tags: swift, thread-safety, actor

I'm trying to understand if my code is really thread safe. The read/write to `storeData` should be, but is the call to `sync` in `didSet` also thread safe?

Also, is there a better practice to load initial data in actors? Feels weird to initialize `Task` in the constructor.

```
actor Store<Element: Codable>: StoreType {
    private let fileName: String
    private var storeData: [Element]? {
        didSet {
            sync()
        }
    }
    
    init(fileName: String) {
        self.fileName = fileName
        
        Task {
            await loadFromPlist()
        }
    }
    
    func read() async throws -> [Element]? {
        storeData
    }
    
    func write(_ value: [Element]) async throws {
        storeData = value
    }
    
    func remove() async throws {
        storeData = nil
    }
}

private extension Store {
    func loadFromPlist() {
        let decoder = PropertyListDecoder()
        
        guard let data = try? Data.init(contentsOf: plistURL),
              let elements = try? decoder.decode([Element].self, from: data) else {
            return
        }
        
        storeData = elements
    }
    
    private func sync() {
        let encoder = PropertyListEncoder()
        guard let data = try? encoder.encode(storeData) else {
            return
        }
        
        if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: plistURL.path) {
            try? data.write(to: plistURL)
        } else {
            FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: plistURL.path, contents: data, attributes: nil)
        }
    }
    
    var plistURL: URL {
        let documents = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
        return documents.appendingPathComponent("\(fileName).plist")
    }
}
```

Comment: This code looks fine in isolation (heh), but its API might push for it to be used in a way that _isn't_ thread safe. Consider: `store.write(store.read() + [1, 2, 3])`. The read and write are thread safe on their own, but their composition together into a read-modify-write pattern is _not_ thread safe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is "thread-safe" in that at every point, `storeData` is a valid Swift value. You will never crash due to a low-level data race. Reading `storeData` will always return an array with "something" in it. And this code will never corrupt the plist file.

This code is not "thread-safe" in that there is definitely a surprising situation during init.

```
let store = Store<String>(fileName: "x")
let oldValues = try await store.read()
// What is oldValues? Might be empty. Might be the contents of the file.
```

There is no promise that your `init` Task will be run before or after `read`. So you don't know what will be there.

Since reading the file is inherently an async event that may fail, I'd recommend marking your `init` with async and throws. Then you don't need a Task, and everything makes sense. And there's no reason to make `read()` async or throws.

Alternately, you could delay loading the file until `read()`, which is currently async and throws. I'd use the Optional to keep track of whether the data is loaded, rather than ever returning an Optional here.